# CSS Expression to GSS for Conditional Property in GWT?

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, google-closure

How can I transform the following GWT CSS part into the GWT GSS?

```
@if (test.mobile.client.Parameter.getWindowWidth() >= 414) {
 .previewBox {
    width: 33.333333%;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@if (eval("test.mobile.client.Parameter.getWindowWidth() >= 414")) {
    .previewBox {
        width: 33.333333%;
    }
}
```